Applying local unitary operator of one qubit on an entangled state
Suppose I have the following Bell state where
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$
And the following unitary operator
$A(\theta_{1})$ and $B(\theta_{2})$ meaning they are dependent on a different variable $\theta$ and preform some rotation (Both are a 2 x 2 matrix).
and given the new state
$$(A(\theta_{1}) \otimes B(\theta_{2}))|\psi\rangle$$
I saw in a lecture that local unitary operators that preform rotation don't change the entanglement of a state such that the new state is still entangled.
I can't find any formal proof and would be happy to have a link to one or an explanation.

It is probably easiest to argue by contradiction: assume that there existed angles $\theta_1,\theta_2$ such that $(A(\theta_1)\otimes B(\theta_2))|\psi\rangle$ were separable. Hence, by definition, there exist pure states $|\psi_A\rangle,|\psi_B\rangle$ on the respective subsystem such that
$$
(A(\theta_1)\otimes B(\theta_2))|\psi\rangle=|\psi_A\rangle\otimes|\psi_B\rangle\,.
$$
But $A,B$ are unitary so we can simply apply their inverse:
\begin{align*}
A(-\theta_1)|\psi_A\rangle\otimes B(-\theta_2)|\psi_B\rangle&=(A(-\theta_1)\otimes B(-\theta_2))(|\psi_A\rangle\otimes|\psi_B\rangle)\\
&=(A(-\theta_1)\otimes B(-\theta_2))(A(\theta_1)\otimes B(\theta_2))|\psi\rangle\\
&=\big(\big(A(-\theta_1)A(\theta_1)\big)\otimes\big(B(-\theta_2)B(\theta_2)\big)\big)|\psi\rangle\\
&=({\bf1}_A\otimes{\bf1}_B)|\psi\rangle={\bf1}|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle\,.
\end{align*}
This shows that $|\psi\rangle$ is the product state $A(-\theta_1)|\psi_A\rangle\otimes B(-\theta_2)|\psi_B\rangle$, hence separable. But this contradicts that $|\psi\rangle$ was assumed to be entangled -- so we have to conclude that $(A(\theta_1)\otimes B(\theta_2))|\psi\rangle$ can never be separable if $|\psi\rangle$ is entangled.
